# Error inflating class fragment Duplicate ID, tag null, or parent id with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment

Tags: android, android-fragment

En una app , estoy tratando  de monstrar un mapa en un Dialog en forma de pop up.. El pop up que contiene mi mapa activa cuando mi button SlideToActView está completo.. la primera vez me carga el mapa con la ubicación actual .... pero si vuelva a activar este mismo button para ver el mapa de nuevo , crashea la app y me tira este error...

```
Duplicate id 0x7f0a00a2, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0a0004 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

intenté solucionarlo recargando el activity con el recreate(); la segunda vez no carga el mapa..
ahí está mi código

```
  slideToActView = (SlideToActView) findViewById(R.id.example_gray_on_green);
    slideToActView.setOnSlideCompleteListener(new SlideToActView.OnSlideCompleteListener() {
        @Override
    public void onSlideComplete(SlideToActView slideToActView) {
        PopupMap();
        slideToActView.resetSlider();
    }
});
private void PopupMap() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Principal.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_popup);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    //dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = animationSource;
    ImageView imgclose = dialog.findViewById(R.id.imgClose);
    getLocationPermission();/* Ahi arranca el mapa*/

    imgclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
           //recreate /*intente recargar la pagina con recreate(); esta vez no carga el mapa la segunda vez*/
        }
    });
    dialog.show();


}
```

ahi esta el proceso donde se carga el mapa

```
  private void getLocationPermission() {
    Log.d("", "getLocationPermission: getting location permissions");
    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
            FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                COURSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
            //getDeviceLocation();
            initMap();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                permissions,
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
 private void initMap() {
    Log.d("", "initMap: initializing map");
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapPrincipal);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) Principal.this);
}
```

Comment: agrega por favor lo que realiza getLocationPermission()  o donde inicializa el mapa

Comment: Ahí lo agregue lo que realiza getlocationPermission() gracias @Jorgesys